# What is the best way to extract text from a pdf that is structured using multilevel list headings?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, text-processing, text-extraction

I have a large PDF document that contains hundreds of clauses that are structured under numbered multi-level list headings.

Here's one page of the [PDF](https://docdro.id/rduS8oC).

I need to extract all the text that is directly below each lowest-level list heading.

> ## 13. HEADING
>
> > ### 13.1 Sub-Heading
> >
> > > > #### 13.1.1 Lowest-Level Child Heading
> > > >
> > > > Example paragraph of text that I need to extract (along with the above heading) and output it to a text/csv file so I can add it to an excel sheet.

I have already managed to convert the pdf file to a text file using [pdfminer](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six)'s *pdf2txt.py* tool.

To install pdfminer: `python -m pip install pdfminer.six`

The command I used to convert pdf to text was: `pdf2txt.py -o output.txt -t text doc.pdf`

The headings need to go into a column in [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2jBX.jpg), with their corresponding paragraph of text going in the cell beside them (in the adjacent column). In the excel link the headings go in column C and the text goes in column D.
Should I use regex or is there an easier or more effective method? Just looking for some pointers on how to extract this information properly. Advice or code would be appreciated.

Comment: If you land here looking for an answer then you might find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58156753/9028253