# Regular expression to extract chunks of text from a text file?

Tags: python, regex, text, text-extraction

I need to extract headings and the chunk of text beneath them from a text file in Python using regular expression but I'm finding it difficult.

I converted this [PDF](https://www.docdroid.net/rduS8oC/pdfsam-doc.pdf) to text so that it now looks like this:

[image: img]

So far I have been able to get all the numerical headers (12.4.5.4, 12.4.5.6, 13, 13.1, 13.1.1, 13.1.12) using the following regex:

```
import re

with open('data/single.txt', encoding='UTF-8') as file:

    for line in file:
        headings = re.findall(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?', line)
        print(headings)`
```

I just don't know how to get the worded part of those headings or the paragraph of text beneath them.

**EDIT** - Here is the text:

I.S. EN 60601-1:2006&A1:2013&AC:2014&A12:2014

60601-1 © IEC:2005 
60601-1 © IEC:2005

– 337 – 
– 169 –

12.4.5.4  Other ME EQUIPMENT producing diagnostic or therapeutic radiation 
When  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in  the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the 
RISKS associated  with  ME EQUIPMENT  producing  diagnostic or therapeutic radiation  other  than 
for diagnostic X-rays and radiotherapy (see 12.4.5.2 and 12.4.5.3).

Compliance is checked by inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT FILE.

12.4.6  Diagnostic or therapeutic acoustic pressure 
When  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in  the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the 
RISKS associated with diagnostic or therapeutic acoustic pressure.

Compliance is checked by inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT FILE.

13  *  HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS and fault conditions

13.1  Specific HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS

- General

13.1.1 
When  applying  the  SINGLE  FAULT  CONDITIONS  as  described  in  4.7  and listed  in  13.2,  one  at  a 
time,  none  of  the  HAZARDOUS  SITUATIONS  in  13.1.2  to  13.1.4  (inclusive)  shall  occur  in  the 
ME EQUIPMENT.

The failure of any one component at a time, which could result in a  HAZARDOUS  SITUATION, is 
described in 4.7.

- Emissions, deformation of ENCLOSURE or exceeding maximum temperature

13.1.2 
The following HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS shall not occur: 
–  emission  of  flames,  molten  metal,  poisonous  or  ignitable  substance  in  hazardous

quantities;

–  deformation of ENCLOSURES to such an extent that compliance with 15.3.1 is impaired; 
–

temperatures  of  APPLIED  PARTS exceeding  the  allowed  values  identified  in  Table  24  when 
measured as described in 11.1.3; 
temperatures  of  ME EQUIPMENT  parts  that  are  not  APPLIED  PARTS but  are  likely  to  be 
touched,  exceeding  the  allowable  values  in  Table  23  when  measured  and  adjusted  as 
described in 11.1.3;

–

–  exceeding the allowable values for “other components and materials” identified in Table 22 
times 1,5 minus 12,5 °C. Limits for windings are found in Table 26, Table 27 and Table 31. 
In all other cases, the allowable values of Table 22 apply.

Temperatures shall be measured using the method described in 11.1.3.

The  SINGLE  FAULT  CONDITIONS  in  4.7,  8.1 b),  8.7.2  and  13.2.2,  with  regard  to  the  emission  of 
flames,  molten  metal  or  ignitable  substances,  shall  not  be  applied  to  parts  and  components 
where: 
–  The  construction  or  the  supply  circuit  limits  the  power  dissipation  in  SINGLE  FAULT

CONDITION to less than 15 W or the energy dissipation to less than 900 J.

Comment: Can you add the text of `data/single.txt` to the question instead of a link to the pdf? What do you want to match exactly? Only 1 following paragraph or also the text following the paragraph number?

Comment: Sure! Just added the text now.

Comment: If you want to match the paragraphs with the following text until the next one try `^\d+(?:\.\d+)* +.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* ).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/eHXZ8x/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your pattern and match a space after it followed by the rest of the line.

Then repeat matching all following lines that do not start with a heading.

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)* .*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* ).*)*
```

- `^\d+(?:.\d+)*`  Your pattern to match a heading followed by a space
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

    - `\d+(?:.\d+)*`  The heading pattern
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close the non capturing group and repeat 0+ times to match all the lines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlhnaT/1)

Comment: That regex works great. It finds the headings really well! Thanks. 
When you say _"repeat matching all following lines that do not start with a heading"_ does that mean I add to the regex you gave or create some sort of if statement with a different regex? Sorry if that's a stupid question.

Comment: That is not a stupid question at all. The pattern should first match the heading followed by the rest of the line. Then when at the end of the line you want to keep on matching a newline and the whole following line as long as is does not start with the pattern that matches the heading. You don't have to add anything to the pattern as that part is taken care  of by the negative lookahead right after matching a newline `(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* `

Comment: Okay so my output is much different to the one on the regex demo. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Here's a link to the output: https://docdro.id/1hBvQXr I am still trying to figure this out even though I feel the answer is obvious. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Instead of reading the file line by line, you could try reading the whole file and then use findall.

Comment: Okay, will try that now. That sounds blindingly obvious now that I read it.

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. That worked. 
```import re
with open('data/single.txt', encoding='UTF-8') as infile, open('data/soutput.txt', "w") as outfile:
    content = infile.read()
    regex = r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)* +.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* ).*)*'
      
    output = re.findall(regex, content, re.M)
    outfile.write(f'{output}\n')```

Comment: @wuddadid While the other answer would also work, you might check the number of steps of the regex101 demo links to compare the efficiency of both patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=^\d+(?:\.\d+)*)|^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+([\s\S]*)
```

might be somewhat close to get those desired texts that I'm guessing.

---

Here we'd simply look for lines that'd start with,

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+
```

then, we'd simply collect anything afterwards using

```
([\s\S]*?)
```

upto the next line that'd start with,

```
(?=^\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
```

Then, we may or may not, depending on how our input may look like, have only one last element left, which we would collect that using this last:

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+([\s\S]*)
```

which we would then alter (using `|`) to the prior expression.

Even though, this method is simple to code, it's pretty slow performance-wise since we're using lookarounds, so [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58156753/6553328) is much better, if time complexity would be a concern, which is likely to be.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/A1JWEd/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=^\d+(?:\.\d+)*)|^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s+([\s\S]*)"
string = """

I.S. EN 60601-1:2006&A1:2013&AC:2014&A12:2014

60601-1 © IEC:2005 
60601-1 © IEC:2005

– 337 – 
– 169 –

12.4.5.4  Other ME EQUIPMENT producing diagnostic or therapeutic radiation 
When  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in  the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the 
RISKS associated  with  ME EQUIPMENT  producing  diagnostic or therapeutic radiation  other  than 
for diagnostic X-rays and radiotherapy (see 12.4.5.2 and 12.4.5.3). 

Compliance is checked by inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT FILE.

12.4.6  Diagnostic or therapeutic acoustic pressure 
When  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in  the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the 
RISKS associated with diagnostic or therapeutic acoustic pressure. 

Compliance is checked by inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT FILE.

13  *  HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS and fault conditions

13.1  Specific HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS

*  General 

13.1.1 
When  applying  the  SINGLE  FAULT  CONDITIONS  as  described  in  4.7  and listed  in  13.2,  one  at  a 
time,  none  of  the  HAZARDOUS  SITUATIONS  in  13.1.2  to  13.1.4  (inclusive)  shall  occur  in  the 
ME EQUIPMENT.

The failure of any one component at a time, which could result in a  HAZARDOUS  SITUATION, is 
described in 4.7. 

*  Emissions, deformation of ENCLOSURE or exceeding maximum temperature 

13.1.2 
The following HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS shall not occur: 
–  emission  of  flames,  molten  metal,  poisonous  or  ignitable  substance  in  hazardous 

quantities; 

–  deformation of ENCLOSURES to such an extent that compliance with 15.3.1 is impaired; 
– 

temperatures  of  APPLIED  PARTS exceeding  the  allowed  values  identified  in  Table  24  when 
measured as described in 11.1.3; 
temperatures  of  ME EQUIPMENT  parts  that  are  not  APPLIED  PARTS but  are  likely  to  be 
touched,  exceeding  the  allowable  values  in  Table  23  when  measured  and  adjusted  as 
described in 11.1.3; 

– 

–  exceeding the allowable values for “other components and materials” identified in Table 22 
times 1,5 minus 12,5 °C. Limits for windings are found in Table 26, Table 27 and Table 31. 
In all other cases, the allowable values of Table 22 apply. 

Temperatures shall be measured using the method described in 11.1.3. 

The  SINGLE  FAULT  CONDITIONS  in  4.7,  8.1 b),  8.7.2  and  13.2.2,  with  regard  to  the  emission  of 
flames,  molten  metal  or  ignitable  substances,  shall  not  be  applied  to  parts  and  components 
where: 
–  The  construction  or  the  supply  circuit  limits  the  power  dissipation  in  SINGLE  FAULT 

CONDITION to less than 15 W or the energy dissipation to less than 900 J. 

"""

print(re.findall(regex, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

> [('12.4.5.4', 'Other ME EQUIPMENT producing diagnostic or therapeutic
>   radiation \nWhen  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in 
>   the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the \nRISKS associated  with  ME
>   EQUIPMENT  producing  diagnostic or therapeutic radiation  other  than
>   \nfor diagnostic X-rays and radiotherapy (see 12.4.5.2 and 12.4.5.3).
>   \n\nCompliance is checked by inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT
>   FILE.\n\n', '', ''), ('12.4.6', 'Diagnostic or therapeutic acoustic
>   pressure \nWhen  applicable,  the  MANUFACTURER  shall  address  in 
>   the  RISK  MANAGEMENT PROCESS  the \nRISKS associated with diagnostic
>   or therapeutic acoustic pressure. \n\nCompliance is checked by
>   inspection of the RISK MANAGEMENT FILE.\n\n', '', ''), ('13', '* 
>   HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS and fault conditions\n\n', '', ''), ('13.1',
>   'Specific HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS\n\n*  General \n\n', '', ''),
>   ('13.1.1', 'When  applying  the  SINGLE  FAULT  CONDITIONS  as 
>   described  in  4.7  and listed  in  13.2,  one  at  a \ntime,  none 
>   of  the  HAZARDOUS  SITUATIONS  in  13.1.2  to  13.1.4  (inclusive) 
>   shall  occur  in  the \nME EQUIPMENT.\n\nThe failure of any one
>   component at a time, which could result in a  HAZARDOUS  SITUATION, is
>   \ndescribed in 4.7. \n\n*  Emissions, deformation of ENCLOSURE or
>   exceeding maximum temperature \n\n', '', ''), ('', '', '13.1.2', 'The
>   following HAZARDOUS SITUATIONS shall not occur: \n–  emission  of 
>   flames,  molten  metal,  poisonous  or  ignitable  substance  in 
>   hazardous \n\nquantities; \n\n–  deformation of ENCLOSURES to such an
>   extent that compliance with 15.3.1 is impaired; \n– \n\ntemperatures 
>   of  APPLIED  PARTS exceeding  the  allowed  values  identified  in 
>   Table  24  when \nmeasured as described in 11.1.3; \ntemperatures  of 
>   ME EQUIPMENT  parts  that  are  not  APPLIED  PARTS but  are  likely 
>   to  be \ntouched,  exceeding  the  allowable  values  in  Table  23 
>   when  measured  and  adjusted  as \ndescribed in 11.1.3; \n\n– \n\n– 
>   exceeding the allowable values for “other components and materials”
>   identified in Table 22 \ntimes 1,5 minus 12,5 °C. Limits for windings
>   are found in Table 26, Table 27 and Table 31. \nIn all other cases,
>   the allowable values of Table 22 apply. \n\nTemperatures shall be
>   measured using the method described in 11.1.3. \n\nThe  SINGLE  FAULT 
>   CONDITIONS  in  4.7,  8.1 b),  8.7.2  and  13.2.2,  with  regard  to 
>   the  emission  of \nflames,  molten  metal  or  ignitable  substances,
>   shall  not  be  applied  to  parts  and  components \nwhere: \n–  The 
>   construction  or  the  supply  circuit  limits  the  power 
>   dissipation  in  SINGLE  FAULT \n\nCONDITION to less than 15 W or the
>   energy dissipation to less than 900 J. \n\n')]

Comment: I was eventually able to recreate the same output as yours late last night. Do you think you'd be able to briefly explain your regex as I think I'm going to go with your answer...It seems more in line with what I've been looking for. It needs a little adjusting and I think I'd be able to do it myself if I understood it a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to their detailed answers and helpful explanations I ended up combining parts of both @The-fourth-bird's code and @Emma's code into this regex which seems to work nicely for what I need.

```
(^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s+)((?![a-z])[\s\S].*(?:\r?\n))([\s\S]*?)(?=^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s+(?![a-z]))
```

Here is the [REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5Wqv6j/1).

I does what I want, which is splitting the (numerical heading), (worded heading) and the (body of text) into groups separated by commas which allow me to separate them into columns in Excel by using the custom delimiter **), (** and some other post processing.

The nice thing about this new regex is that it skips numbered headings that are just references and not actually headings as seen here:

[image: img]

Comment: Why not use https://regex101.com/r/034ARv/1 `^(\d+(?:\.\d+)*) (.*)((?:\r?\n(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* ).*)*)` It takes less steps.

Comment: For the specific use case that I listed, this provided the best result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdfplumber
import re
pdfToString = ""

with pdfplumber.open(r"sample.pdf") as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        print(page.extract_text())
        pdfToString += page.extract_text()

matches = re.findall(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)* .*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)* ).*)*',pdfToString, re.M)
for i in  matches:
    if "word_to_extract" in i[:50]:
        print(i)
```

This solution is to extract all the headings which has same format of headings in the question and to extract the required heading and the paragraphs that follows it.